# .Include() Not Pulling Additional Resource

Tags: ajax, linq, api, asp.net-core

I have a JS file making an AJAX request to a controller. The code below works without the `.Include()` method but when I add it, the app runs but it doesn't populate my code. I tried running in debug mode but I'm not getting clear answers.

**JS file**

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:5001/api/SortData/All",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(response => {
    // For each element in the response, add the submission card
    $(response).each(index => {
        // Formatting the submission date to be legible
        var date = getFormattedDate(response[index].submitDate);
        // Adding each submission card to the dashboard
        $(".proposals").append(` ...some html...`)}});
```

**API**

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class SortDataController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet, ActionName("All")]
    public IQueryable<Proposals> GetAllProposals()
    {
        return _context.Proposals.Include(p => p.DeveloperName.Name);
    }
}
```

**Proposals Model**

```
public class Proposals
{
    public Proposals()
    {
        // Adding values to fields automatically. These fields are not on the form for users to see and update.
        SubmitDate = DateTime.Now;
        StatusId = 14;
        AssignedTo = "johnDoe";
    }

    // other properties

    [NotMapped]
    public Users DeveloperName { get; set; }

    // a few more properties
}
```

**Users Model**

```
public partial class Users
{
    // other properties

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //some more properties

    public IList<Proposals> Proposals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might need to use `ThenInclude`, e.g. `.Include(p => p.DeveloperName).ThenInclude(dn => dn.Name);`. I might be *completely wrong* as I don't know this stuff well, but seeing as no-one's said anything yet it might be worth at least trying that. I'm also suspicious of that `[NotMapped]`, but, like I said, I dunno what I'm talking about. :)

Comment: First of all .Why did you used the **NotMapped** attribute? I think it affects the results.
 and then use the **IActionResult** return type and try this: 
**_context.Proposals.Include(p => p.DeveloperName).ToList();

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thank you for the suggestion. `ThenInclude()` didn't work. I was suspicious about the `[NotMapped]` too but it's been there before I added the AJAX code and it worked. Before I used AJAX, I just used an `OnGet()` method in the code behind. It allowed me to use the `ThenInclude()`.

Comment: @ArminTorkashvand My understanding of the `[NotMapped]` attribute is that it annotates properties that don't correspond to a column in the DB that is represented by the Model. The DeveloperName property is in the User's model.

Answer (score 2):

The `Include` is for the Navigation property only, so instead of using  `Include(p => p.DeveloperName.Name)` try to use `Include(p => p.DeveloperName)` which will also contains `Name` when you retrieve data.

```
return _context.Proposals.Include(p => p.DeveloperName);
```

If you only would like a few specific fields,you need to select them explicitly. Something like this would work:

```
_context.Proposals.Include(p => p.DeveloperName)
.Select(p => new Proposals
{
    StatusId = p.StatusId ,
    // etc... The fields you need from Proposals go here
    DeveloperName = new Users
    {
        Name = p.Category.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but the above code doesn't work. It doesn't show anything. And I can't use the Select statement because it seems to be creating a new proposal with the "new" keyword. It populates the same proposals a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out Blue's Clues.

Turns out, I had to add

`.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);`

to the end of `services.AddMvc()` in my StartUp. Apparently, there was some looping issue that this code prevents.

I also updated my API Controller to...

```
[Route("api/SortData")]
public class SortDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("All")]
    public IActionResult GetAllProposals()
    {
        return Ok(_context.Proposals.Include(p => p.DeveloperName).Include(p => p.Status).ToList());

    }
}
```

From there, I was able to see the JSON response in the XHR and add it accordingly to my JS file.